# проверка введённого пользователем пин-кода

Tags: javascript

Хочу чтобы функция возвращала **true** если пользователь ввёл 4 или 6 цифр. И **false** во всех остальных случаях. Ввёл буквы, больше символов и т.д.

```
validatePIN("1234") === true
validatePIN("12345") === false
validatePIN("a234") === false
```

Код функции:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  if (pin.length == 4) {
    return true;
  } else if (pin.length == 6) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;

}
```

Как мне грамотно организовать проверку, того что в строке нет символов, кроме цифр от 1 до 9.

Решение с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{6})$
```

П.с. если кто знает покажите как сделать без RegExp

Comment: Цифра `0` не допускается?

Comment: Заодно добавьте причину, почему регулярки нежелательны.

Comment: цифра 0 допускается. любые 4 или 6 цифр

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian я плохо читаю пока регулярные выражения. они вызывают затруднения

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что остальным читать код такой проверки без использования регулярок вызовет больше затруднений.

Comment: То, что вы хотите реализовать эту задачу без регулярных выражений означает одно из двух: 1) вы не знаете регулярные выражения и боитесь их использовать или 2) вы считаете, что они работают медленно. По второму пункту сразу вас успокою - быстрее вы не напишите. По первому пункту - сейчас у вас отличная возможность научиться, потому что задача очень маленькая и простая.

Comment: буду рад любой помощи. если это проще реализовать именно с регулярными выражениями, пожалуйста. Покажите буду разбираться.

Comment: вот вам с объяснениями https://regex101.com/r/uU0nB8/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну если без регулярок, то вот так:

```js
function validatePIN(pin) {
  var i = pin.length;

  if (i != 4 && i != 6) {
    return false;
  }

  while (i--) {
    if (pin[i] < '0' || pin[i] > '9') {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log('should be true:');
console.log(validatePIN('1234'));
console.log(validatePIN('0129'));
console.log(validatePIN('123456'));

console.log('should be false:');
console.log(validatePIN('12345'));
console.log(validatePIN('a234'));
console.log(validatePIN('123a'));
console.log(validatePIN('-123'));
console.log(validatePIN('1.23'));
console.log(validatePIN('0x99'));
console.log(validatePIN('0:29'));
console.log(validatePIN('0/29'));
```

Comment: 12 редакций? Что так?

Comment: @Other синдром вахтера во мне лютует )

Comment: Известный диагноз, сам страдаю, правда 12 - это мощно, Вам, батенька, к врачу бы, он лечебные посиделки на вахте пропишет...

Comment: @Other интересно, если откатить до первой ревизии, а потом сразу в неё последний вариант вставить, как это будет отображаться, как 13 редакций?

Comment: Рискните! Плюс медальку получите за откат.

Comment: @Other ну, медаль уже имеется такая, но я попробую )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42961/discussion-between-other-and-vladimir-gamalian).

Answer (score 2):

Диапазон ASCII

```js
function validatePIN(pin, valid = true) {
  
  l = pin.length;
  if(l != 4 && l != 6) return false;
  
  Array.from(pin).forEach((s) => {
    s = s.charCodeAt(0);
    if(s > 57 || s < 48) valid = false;
  });
  
  return valid;
}

console.log(validatePIN("1234"));
console.log(validatePIN("0123"));
console.log(validatePIN("123456"));

console.log(validatePIN("12345"));
console.log(validatePIN("a234"));
console.log(validatePIN("123a"));
console.log(validatePIN("-123"));
console.log(validatePIN("1.23"));
console.log(validatePIN("0x99"));
console.log(validatePIN("0:29"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Или такой вариант:

```js
function validatePIN(pin) {

  if (isNaN(pin) || pin == 'null' || !isInteger(+pin)) {
    return false;
  } else if (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isInteger(num) {
  return (num ^ 0) === num;
}


console.log(validatePIN("123454")); //=== true
console.log(validatePIN("1234")); //=== true
console.log(validatePIN("a234")); //=== false
console.log(validatePIN("a23445")); //=== false 
console.log(validatePIN('null')); //=== false
console.log(validatePIN('1.23')); //=== false
```

Comment: Для `validatePIN("-123")` даст ошибочно `true`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian исправил и добавил доп проверки.

Comment: Теперь для `validatePIN("1.23")`

Comment: спасибо за участие, но такой код не проходит validatePIN(.234)

Comment: Исправил. Теперь все проходит))

Comment: Что-то он теперь для всех вариантов `false` выдает.

Comment: Ага, поторопился)) Сейчас по работе разгребу и подредактирую))

Comment: Исправил. Теперь все должно работать)

Comment: Теперь пропускает "0x99"